# Custom top app bar with children drawn outside of parent bounds - Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a custom top app bar in Compose and Material3 (using `TopAppBarLayout` as base), that has a row of buttons running along the bottom edge. I want the row to spill past the bottom boundary and appear over content body of the Scaffold. Within the layout inspector, it seems that the row of buttons is placed in the correct spot, however the content body is covering the bottom part of the row:

[image]

I've looked at the `Scaffold` source to see if the placement issue is there, but it looks correct to me (content body is placed first, followed by top bar):

```
        // Placing to control drawing order to match default elevation of each placeable

        bodyContentPlaceables.forEach {
            it.place(0, 0)
        }
        topBarPlaceables.forEach {
            it.place(0, 0)
        }
```

Swapping those around had no effect in any case. I also tried adding `Modifier.wrapContentHeight(unbounded = true)` in various spots, but none of them did what I was after.

This code is essentially `TopAppBarLayout` with the button row added to it:

```
@Composable
private fun TopAppBarLayout(
    modifier: Modifier,
    heightPx: Float,
    navigationIconContentColor: Color,
    titleContentColor: Color,
    actionIconContentColor: Color,
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle,
    titleAlpha: Float,
    titleVerticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical,
    titleHorizontalArrangement: Arrangement.Horizontal,
    titleBottomPadding: Int,
    hideTitleSemantics: Boolean,
    navigationIcon: @Composable () -> Unit,
    actions: @Composable () -> Unit,
    buttons: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .layoutId("navigationIcon")
                    .padding(start = TopAppBarHorizontalPadding)
            ) {
                CompositionLocalProvider(
                    LocalContentColor provides navigationIconContentColor,
                    content = navigationIcon
                )
            }
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .layoutId("title")
                    .padding(horizontal = TopAppBarHorizontalPadding)
                    .then(if (hideTitleSemantics) Modifier.clearAndSetSemantics { } else Modifier)
            ) {
                ProvideTextStyle(value = titleTextStyle) {
                    CompositionLocalProvider(
                        LocalContentColor provides titleContentColor.copy(alpha = titleAlpha),
                        content = title
                    )
                }
            }
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .layoutId("actionIcons")
                    .padding(end = TopAppBarHorizontalPadding)
            ) {
                CompositionLocalProvider(
                    LocalContentColor provides actionIconContentColor,
                    content = actions
                )
            }
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .layoutId("buttons")
                    .wrapContentHeight(unbounded = true)
            ) {
                CompositionLocalProvider(
                    LocalContentColor provides Color.Red,
                    content = buttons
                )
            }
        },
        modifier = modifier
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val navigationIconPlaceable =
            measurables.first { it.layoutId == "navigationIcon" }
                .measure(constraints.copy(minWidth = 0))
        val actionIconsPlaceable =
            measurables.first { it.layoutId == "actionIcons" }
                .measure(constraints.copy(minWidth = 0))

        val maxTitleWidth = if (constraints.maxWidth == Constraints.Infinity) {
            constraints.maxWidth
        } else {
            (constraints.maxWidth - navigationIconPlaceable.width - actionIconsPlaceable.width)
                .coerceAtLeast(0)
        }
        val titlePlaceable =
            measurables.first { it.layoutId == "title" }
                .measure(constraints.copy(minWidth = 0, maxWidth = maxTitleWidth))

        // Locate the title's baseline.
        val titleBaseline =
            if (titlePlaceable[LastBaseline] != AlignmentLine.Unspecified) {
                titlePlaceable[LastBaseline]
            } else {
                0
            }

        val buttonRowPlaceable =
            measurables.first { it.layoutId == "buttons" }
                .measure(constraints.copy(minWidth = 0))

        val layoutHeight = heightPx.roundToInt()

        layout(constraints.maxWidth, layoutHeight) {
            // Navigation icon
            navigationIconPlaceable.placeRelative(
                x = 0,
                y = (layoutHeight - navigationIconPlaceable.height) / 2
            )

            // Title
            titlePlaceable.placeRelative(
                x = when (titleHorizontalArrangement) {
                    Arrangement.Center -> (constraints.maxWidth - titlePlaceable.width) / 2
                    Arrangement.End ->
                        constraints.maxWidth - titlePlaceable.width - actionIconsPlaceable.width
                    // Arrangement.Start.
                    // An TopAppBarTitleInset will make sure the title is offset in case the
                    // navigation icon is missing.
                    else -> max(TopAppBarTitleInset.roundToPx(), navigationIconPlaceable.width)
                },
                y = when (titleVerticalArrangement) {
                    Arrangement.Center -> (layoutHeight - titlePlaceable.height) / 2
                    // Apply bottom padding from the title's baseline only when the Arrangement is
                    // "Bottom".
                    Arrangement.Bottom ->
                        if (titleBottomPadding == 0) layoutHeight - titlePlaceable.height
                        else layoutHeight - titlePlaceable.height - max(
                            0,
                            titleBottomPadding - titlePlaceable.height + titleBaseline
                        )
                    // Arrangement.Top
                    else -> 0
                }
            )

            // Action icons
            actionIconsPlaceable.placeRelative(
                x = constraints.maxWidth - actionIconsPlaceable.width,
                y = (layoutHeight - actionIconsPlaceable.height) / 2
            )

            // Button row
            buttonRowPlaceable.placeRelative(
                x = 0,
                y = layoutHeight - buttonRowPlaceable.height / 2,
            )
        }
    }
}
```